# Is there the tool than can automatically and silently install required dev tools/packages onto a machine in one go

Tags: language-agnostic

I am looking for a tool (open source preferred) that can install required software (like ASP.NET MVC, etc) onto my machine in one go. Once I knew there is an open source tool for Windows but I forget the name. Hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://chocolatey.org/ can be scripted and has a good collection of packages. Give that a try.